# Dynamically generate child classes based on input

Tags: c#, parent-child, dynamically-generated

I'm currently working on an app that simulates a hotel. The hotels get loaded in via a JSON file, deserialized. The JSON file exists out of all special rooms (listed below), if there is a coordinate missing, it's a hallway.

Example:
Let's say there are 3 different type of rooms:
 - Bedroom
 - Restaurant
 - Storage

Each room has an X and Y position and dimension. A bedroom has a rating, a restaurant has a menu and a storage room has a storage capacity.

So a part of a given JSON file would be something like:

```
{"RoomType" : "Bedroom", "Position" : "1, 2", "dimensions" : "1, 1", "rating" : "3 stars"}, 
{"RoomType" : "restaurant", "Position" : "2, 3", "dimensions" : "2, 1"} //menu not important
```

I started with an abstract class `Room` and want to create the appropriate child classes based on the information in the JSON file.

How do I make it so the appropriate rooms get created on the appropriate locations, or is there a much better way to do so? Please add a short explanation with the code.

EDIT: A different option is with the use of a factory-pattern.

Comment: A factory with delegates or a switch seems to be to be the easiest option.

Comment: @git I've looked a bit more into it. From what I understand, I will need an abstract class `Room`, with the dimensions and position. I also need a class for each special type of room inherited from Room. I can create these dynamically based on a string input or something like that (I.E. whatever comes after `RoomType`) with a switch case regulating the input and requested output.

Comment: Question is not really clear.. what you mean with "dynamic"? dynamic as in runtime-generated? if yes, why you need them runtime generated (usage) and where are the actual property definitions (eg. define rating as property in bedroom); if no, go into further detail about what the actual task is and not what you try to do right now

Comment: When the application starts up, it loads in a hotel-layout via a JSON file, and I have to generate classes depending on what the JSON file asks the application to load in. But, using a factory pattern I was able to accomplish this.

Comment: @SanderKoldenhof You dont necessarily need a diffrent subclass for that. You could also use the Interface "IRoom" and then have another Interface for the general type, like sanitary rooms, eg bath, toilet and so on.And then use subclasses. You should keep 2 things in mind. Composition is easier and cleaner, and also YAGNI. If its a smaller application or you have time to really think about it, just inheritance may be fine.